# Prevent setup.py test / pytest from installing extra dependencies

Tags: python, pytest, setuptools

In my CI I have a *build* step, which uses `pip` and is correctly set up using private indexes etc.

Then I have *test* step, which executes `python setup.py test`. 
In this particular case `test` is an alias to `pytest`.

Setuptools and PIP resolve package dependencies differently, which leads to *test* step attempting to re-install some of the packages. I would like to prevent that. Is there a way to do that either with Setuptools configuration (preferable) or with PyTest configuration?

*Update:*

By popular demand repos to exemplify the issue I'm having
https://github.com/vartec/example_repo_setuptools_issue

Comment: Any compelling reason to not just run the `pytest` command directory instead of using setup.py?

Comment: @MrName the reason is that `python setup.py test` _should_ work regardless which particular test runner package uses, be it vanilla unittest, pytest or even something obsolete like nosetests.

Comment: If pytest is already preinstalled, does setuptools install it again? I thought I had this problem, and it was solved by preinstalling the testing framework into the virtualenv.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible sample git repo we can use?

Comment: @TarunLalwani done

Comment: @vartec, a possible solution posted, please have a look and provide feedback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not override test command like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.test import test


class CustomTest(test):
    def run(self):
        self.distribution.install_requires = []
        super().run()


setup(
    name = "test",
    version = "0.0.1",
    install_requires=['non-existing-package'],
    cmdclass={
        "test": CustomTest,
    },
)
```

Comment: That's an interesting workaround. I still hope for less hacky solution, but if nothing else will work, that might

Comment: @vartec, not sure how this is better then just the two liner which does the same job? I just posted the edit on my answer. If you really didn't care about the `install_requires` then why specify them and customize test class and then ignore them? when you can simply ignore them in the first case itself in case of `test` run

Answer (score 6):

So, as I understand, the problem is that setuptools installs the internal dependencies into the local folder (`.eggs` if I remember correctly), not into the normal virtualenv that you use.

And you do not like how setuptools does that. Neither do I, especially when I need a local DevPI server to be used (setuptools ignores that). So I do this way:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['monotonic'],  # just for example
    extras_require={
        'test': ['pytest', 'pytest-timeout'],
        'docs': ['sphinx', 'alabaster'],
    },
)
```

When you need to test, assuming that you create and install virtualenv somehow:

```
pip install -e .[test]
```

Here, `.` is the current directory. `-e` mean editable mode (but can be omitted). `[test]` is a [setuptools "extra"](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). You can declare multiple "extras", and instal them as `pip install mylib[ext1,ext2]` if needed.

Then you can run the tests either way:

```
pytest
python setup.py test
```

The latter one is only if the `test` command is already configured to run pytest (see [pytest integration manual](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#manual-integration)).

The trick is that if `setuptools` can find the test-dependencies in the current environment (virtualenv, pyenv, system python, whatever else), it will not install them as the eggs, and will just use the installed versions.

Actually, you do not even need to declare `tests_require=` in that case, as the libraries are assumed to be installed into the virtualenv. If they were not, the test command will just fail.

Similarly, you can `pip install .[docs]`, and build your docs with `sphinx-build ...` command from the current virtualenv.

Note that the `install_requires` are installed always, no matter with extras you add. So the app/lib itself will be always fully functional, importable and introspectable.

Hopefully, this was the question (if I understood it correctly).

Answer (score 5):

A small modification in `setup.py` specifically applicable for test should do the job

```
import sys

import pkg_resources
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.dist import Distribution

install_requires = [
    'redis~=2.8.0',
    'example_submodule',
]

tests_require = [
    'pytest',
]

original_function = None

if sys.argv[1] == "test":
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
    new_reqs = set()
    for req in install_requires:
        try:
            sets = working_set.resolve(pkg_resources.parse_requirements(req))
        except Exception as ex:
            new_reqs.add(req)
    install_requires = new_reqs


setup(
    name='example_module',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=install_requires,
    tests_require=tests_require,
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    extras_require={
        'testing': tests_require,
    },
    dependency_links=[
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/vartec/example_repo_setuptools_issue_submodule.git#egg=example_submodule-0.1.0',
    ]
)
```

See if this is indeed what you were looking for, if not then provide your feedback.

**Edit-1**

If you really don't care about the `install_requires` in case of `test` then you can just do

```
if sys.argv[1] == "test":
   install_requires = []
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `requirements.txt` file specified dependencies are not in PyPI instead of the `dependency_links` parameter of `setup` method in `setup.py`.

requirements.txt:

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/gentcys/example_repo_setuptools_issue_submodule.git#egg=example_submodule-0.1.0

-e .[testing]
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

install_requires = [
    'redis~=2.10.0',
    'example_submodule',
]

tests_require = [
    'pytest',
]


setup(
    name='example_module',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=install_requires,
    tests_require=tests_require,
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    extras_require={
        'testing': tests_require,
    },
)
```

I forked your example repo and made some changes
https://github.com/gentcys/example_repo_setuptools_issue.git
And i create a submodule repo
https://github.com/gentcys/example_repo_setuptools_issue_submodule.git